# Python argv issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Python 3.0
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = "> "

print("Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name,script))
print("I would like to ask you a few questions.")
print("Do you like me %s?" % user_name)
likes = input(prompt)

print("Where do you live %s?" % user_name)
lives = input(prompt)

print("What kind of computer do you have?")
computer = input(prompt)

print("""
Alright so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure where that is.
And you have a %r computer. Nice.
""" % (likes, lives, computer)
    )
```

I am getting the following error:

```
script, user_name = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
len(argv)
```

to see how many elements `argv` has. Your problem is that there is a mismatch between the number of elements in argv and the number of variables you're trying to assign it to.

Here is a simplified case of your problem:

```
>>> one, two = [1] # cannot do this!
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>> one, two = [1, 2] # this is OK!
```

To fix this, make sure you pass an argument to your script

```
python your_script.py user_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an argument for your program. If you didn't you'll get an error because argv will just contain one argument and it is the name of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a smaller program:

```
from sys import argv
print(argv)
```

And let's run this:

```
[7:30pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] python3 argv.py abc def ghi
['argv.py', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

So in your use case, you need to pass exactly one argument to the script.